# How can generate multiple "flavors" of a target and its dependencies from a single CMake build?

Tags: cmake, target

I use a cmake based build-system. I want to generate two versions of one particular executable differing in

- Certain defines (say set of defines is A in one version and set of defines is B in the other) and
- Libraries that these two versions link against.
- Note that some libraries in the two versions themselves need to be built using the defines in set A or in B.

One way I can think of generating both the executables in a single build are to create multiple targets:

`add_executable(app_A ...)`
`add_executable(app_B ...)`

and then,

`target_link_libraries(app_A lib1_A lib2_A lib3)` `target_link_libraries(app_B lib1_B lib2_B lib3)`.

However, this requires me to also create targets for each library that is shared, and, essentially, maintain two parallel sets of targets all the way through. Is there a better way to do something like this. I really want a single build to generate both flavors of the executable instead of two cmake command with different defines.

Comment: In CMake an executable target denotes a **specifically** compiled and linked the executable file. That is, if you want to compile/link an executable with **different options**, then you need to create **different targets**. If creation of these targets involves many common steps, then you could implement these steps in a function or macro, and call this function (macro) several times. BTW, why you insist on having single build? In many cases it is simpler to configure and build CMake project several times with different options than to maintain several targets hierarchy in a single build.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I am looking at a single build is to reduce compilation overhead on the project. 
If this creation of multiple targets is the only approach possible then, I understand that I will have to evaluate the tradeoff in initial-work + maintainability overhead for maintaining two sets of targets for a bunch of targets vs getting buy-off for a two-build solution from my overlords.